# Blazor Razor page properties in separate file/class

Tags: c#, inheritance, blazor

I have several Razor components with the same properties and methods for the paging of the list.

These properties are in the `@code` part of the razor file.

If this was a regular C# class I would use inheritance, but is that here also possible and how would I do this?

```
@code {
  private bool myProperty { get; set; }

  public async Task ZoekenAsync(ChangeEventArgs args) {
    dosomething();
  }
}
```

Comment: In visual studio right click on `@code` ...

Comment: I often put common features in an empty component, because I like to instantiate them in markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Razor component inherits after ComponentBase. Using `@inherits` directive makes it inherit after a different class. You can use the different class as a base with no problem as long as this class extends (inherits) ComponentBase. It is shown in the docs how to split your code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but didn't know it must inherit from ComponentBase. Now It works!